# how to avoid call to postmessage

Tags: javascript, postmessage

In my application I have Count down functionality which uses setInterval as follows :

```
     this.timer = window.setInterval(() => {
        const time_delta = (this.target_date - new Date() ) / 1000
        if (time_delta > 0) {
            this.days = time_delta / (24 * 3600)
            this.hour = time_delta  % (24 * 3600) / (3600)
            this.minute = (time_delta  % (24 * 3600) % (3600)) / 60
            this.second = time_delta % 60
        } else {
            this.days = 0
            this.hour = 0
            this.minute = 0
            this.second = 0
        }

        if(time_delta <= 1 && time_delta > 0 ){
            clearInterval(this.timer);
            location.reload();
        }
    },10000)
```

Now there is another functionality which has completely different functionality and it inherits postmessage

```
   (function (window, undefined) {
function MessageChannel(group, targetWindow, origin) {
    this._msgNo = 1;
    this._group = group;
    this._origin = '*' || origin;
    this._requestHandler = {};
    this._messageQueue = {};
    this._targetWindow = targetWindow || window.parent;

    window.addEventListener('message', receiveMessage.bind(this), false);
}
 MessageChannel.prototype.subscribeRequestMessage = function (msg, callback) {
    // Some logic
};
  MessageChannel.prototype.unsubscribeRequestMessage = function (msg, callback) {
   // Some logic
};
MessageChannel.prototype.postMessage = function (msg, data, timeout) {
    // Some logic
};
 function receiveMessage(event) {
  // Some logic

}

window.Granite = window.Granite || {};
window.Granite.author = window.Granite.author || {};
window.Granite.author.MessageChannel = MessageChannel;

}(this));
```

The problem I have is that whenever the setInterval executes in every seconds in the Count down timer then the MessageChannel.prototype.postMessage function also executes.

The Count down timer is a component present within an iFrame of a html page and this page also have the code of MessageChannel.prototype.postMessage and its available globally by the framework/tool I am using to build my page. Whenever there is a change in the component then MessageChannel.prototype.postMessage is triggered by the framework.  In this case the timer value changes which triggers postMessage call.
I do not want MessageChannel.prototype.postMessage code to execute. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see how the count down timer can trigger your postMessage function. Is something missing?

Comment: @Evert Thanks for looking into this, sorry for not clear enough. I have updated the question. Does this help to understand?

Comment: so this is a problem with the framework you are using. Is this an open source framework? Does it have documentation? If it's internal, can you change it?